# How to list the List of Objects in descending order?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, c#-4.0

Code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<object> GetDetails()
    {
    ........
    ........
    var employeeList = ....;

    var employees = new List<Object>();

    foreach (var employee in employeeList)
    {
      var record = .....;

        var number = record.Select(x => x.number).FirstOrDefault();
        var name = record.Select(x => x.name).FirstOrDefault();

        projects.Add(
                      new
                      {
                          EmployeeNumber = number,
                          EmployeeName = name
                      });
    }
    return employees;
}
```

I tried following code, but it throws an error message saying that, need to implement the `IComparable`.

```
employees.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

I want to return the employees in descending oreder basd on EmployeeNumber.

Comment: Have you tried `employees.OrderByDescending(x => x.EmployeeNumber);`?

Comment: `EmployeeNumber` is not listing in the intellisense...only `equals, gethashcode, gettype, tostrin`g are listed

Comment: Descending order on based on name or number ?

Comment: At all, I already tried with `employees.OrderByDescending(x => x.EmployeeNumber)` but the `EmployeeNumber` is not listed...I think it is the object initializer..

Comment: Those who downvoted, atleast give the answer.

Comment: @X-TECH, Have you seen the `new` keyword?. Tell me how your code `employees.OrderByDescending(x => x.EmployeeNumber);` will work on this?

Comment: @JohnStephen Why your are using `Object` in `var employees = new List<Object>();`

Comment: `.OrderByDescending(x => ((Employee)x).EmployeeNumber);` ?

Comment: @RoyalBg, What is `Employee` refer to in the question?..I am little confused..Please explain.

Comment: Nothing, just curious if you have list of actual objects, but for some reason they are `List<Object>` ;) you already have some nice answers here in comments and in the answers box. For me it will be better if you use an actual class

Comment: @ Everyone, Below is the solution what I needed. I also tried the code, what you  are all suggesting. But the problem is different. Before downvoting, read the question slowly and fully. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `employees` is a `List<object>` filled with an anonymous type, you can't easily sort it after filling (at least not strongly typed), but if you use `Select` instead of the for each, you can use the anonymous type inside any subsequent linq extensions.

So instead of filling a list with the foreach, sort the source first with something like:

```
employees = employeeList.Select(employee =>
            {
                var record = .....;

                var number = record.Select(x => x.number).FirstOrDefault();
                var name = record.Select(x => x.name).FirstOrDefault();

                return
                              new
                              {
                                  EmployeeNumber = number,
                                  EmployeeName = name
                              };
             }).OrderByDescending(e => e.EmployeeNumber).Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Note, used a `ToList` here to create the list, but you could also enumerate (foreach) the result of OrderByDescending

Comment: List of anonymous type #1

Comment: I guess the `Cast()` method will turn it into `List<Object>` so it can be used normally, because List of anonymous type is pretty unusable outside the method (and for comaptibility with the employees variable which was List<Object> when it was created) ?

Comment: @RoyalBg Exactly, since the OP returns the result as JSON I'm assuming he doesn't need strong typing, so the cast<object> was the easiest way to create a List<object>. The alternative would be to enumerate the orderbydescending result and add those entries to the object list.

Comment: Your solution is excellent. Exactly What I needed. Thank You very much.